# Theoretically estimate network round trip time

Tags: networking

How can the network round trip ping time between 2 countries, say US and China be theoretically investigated? (without using tools like ping and traceroute ofcourse)

Comment: Can you send any data. Like a http request?

Comment: Really all a ping is, is a ICMP protocol for sending a small packet of data, and a remote server sending a packet back, the time between those two packets are the latency or "PING" so you could get/calculate a reading by sending a small HTTP request and measuring time to send and time of response.

Comment: THe problem with theoretically estimate such time depends on alot of momentary factors, such as available bandwidth, network conditions, astronomically conditions if the link is via satellite etc, also what would the destination be. The QoS to the actual destination hop matters. Are you targeting a specific host or just the country in general?

Comment: Obviously a backbone server will be much faster than someone's host running on a 56k modem.

Comment: I don't see how you could possibly be theoretical about it. It depends entirely on practical things like link bandwidths and delays, router counts, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this all via the internet… then it  isn’t possible to estimate the delay as you have no idea where or how the traffic is traversed.

However, if you are looking at leasing a private line… then yes, it is possible.  Large companies do this all the time.

Example;
In a straight line, China is 10,000 Km from LA.

Now, given that light travels through fiber at around 200,000 km/s, it would take 50 milliseconds to travel one way to China from LA … 100ms round trip.

So 100ms is theoretically the fasted you could get between LA and China, if a direct path was used.

As you can see from http://www.cablemap.info/, there isn’t any direct path. However, if you knew what route your traffic was taking, you could calculate a near enough estimate.